# WebForms - what event to use to authenticate ticket passed in the request body?

Tags: authentication, webforms, forms-authentication

That might sound quite trivial, but I could not find a good answer: when the request is coming with a validation ticket in the body of the request, what event is best suited to authenticate the request (and then create FormsAuthenticationTicket and auth cookie for subsequent calls)?

One option is in Page_PreInit in BasePage, another Application_AuthenticateRequest in Global.asax, and yet another FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate in Global.asax.

Any link pointing to the solution will be very helpful.

Pawel

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a link with a definitive answer on this, but from personal experience and from reading the [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it seems that Application_BeginRequest is the best option. I have an application in production for several years using this event for the scenario you describe (transforming an application-specific ticket into an ASP.NET forms authentication ticket).

The problem with using Application_AuthenticateRequest and the others you mention is that it will be too late for controls later in that same request cycle to use the forms authentication cookie that you create.

Here is a simple example. You'd need to fill your custom logic for how the ticket gets validated.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!GetRequestHasValidTicket() )
    {
        string bodyToken = Request.Form["MyTokenName"];
        //custom logic to authenticate token
        bool tokenIsValid = true;
        if (tokenIsValid)
        {
            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("myusername", false);
        }
    }
}

private bool GetRequestHasValidTicket()
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = null;
    try
    {
        ticket = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
    }
    catch { }
    return ticket != null;
}
```

A small problem with BeginRequest is that Context.User is not set yet, so you have to manually check for the valid ticket in order to avoid adding the forms auth ticket to every response. If your application logic is such that the ticket only shows up in the body of the very first request, then you might not need this extra check.

Comment: I chose to use Application_PostAuthenticateRequest so the ASP.NET will validate AuthCookie. It fires shortly after BeginRequest (the order is BeginRequest-AuthenticateRequest-PostAuthenticateRequest). Only if user is not authenticated, I look for the authentication ticket in the incoming request.